# как изменить такой массив

Tags: javascript, php

на данный момент json такой `{ ".": "улан-удэ", "identyfyon": "3", "name_two": "Республика Бурятия", "code": "3", "code_two": "3", "alias": "улан-удэ", "region_name": "Республика Бурятия", "popular": "no", "sort_top": "", "cityname": "Улан-Удэ", "regionname": "Республике Бурятия" },`   как мне его изменить на `"улан-удэ": {"identyfyon": "3", "name_two": "Республика Бурятия", "code": "3", "code_two": "3", "alias": "улан-удэ", "region_name": "Республика Бурятия", "popular": "no", "sort_top": "", "cityname": "Улан-Удэ", "regionname": "Республике Бурятия" },`

Answer (score 0):

```js
const json = '{ ".": "улан-удэ", "identyfyon": "3", "name_two": "Республика Бурятия", "code": "3", "code_two": "3", "alias": "улан-удэ", "region_name": "Республика Бурятия", "popular": "no", "sort_top": "", "cityname": "Улан-Удэ", "regionname": "Республике Бурятия" }';

const obj = JSON.parse(json);
const key = '.';
const newObj = {[obj[key]]: {...obj}};

delete newObj[obj[key][key]];

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: а если мне нужно во всём массиве это сделать ?

Comment: @venomphp используйте `.each` или цикл `for`. Приведите пример массива в вопросе.